# Есть ли возможность в C++ явно задать массив?

Tags: c++, массивы

Как функции передать массив {1,2,3,4} без инициализации массива в отдельной переменной, и что в таком случае должна принимать функция в качестве аргумента. Например

```
void some_fucn( )
{
    //
}
int main()
{
    some_func({ 1,2,3,4,5 });
}
```

Comment: Функции С++ не могут принимать массивы по значению. Передавайте `std::array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно явно задать массив и передать его в функцию. Чтобы передать массив без инициализации в отдельной переменной, вы можете использовать C++11 инициализатор списков (initializer lists) и модифицировать функцию, чтобы она принимала `std::initializer_list.` Вот пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

void some_func(std::initializer_list<int> list)
{
    for (const auto& elem : list)
    {
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    some_func({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
    return 0;
}
```

Здесь `std::initializer_list<int>` позволяет передать список значений, которые будут преобразованы во временный массив. Это позволяет передать список значений в виде `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` прямо в функцию, без необходимости объявления и инициализации массива в отдельной переменной.

Comment: Этот ответ вводит в заблуждение.

Comment: Все же, С++ кривой язык. Сравните с аналогом на Си -- `void foo(int a[], int n) { ... }  main() { ... foo((int[]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 5); ... }`

Comment: Не удержусь от каламбура -- даже GNU не удалось его расправить

Comment: @avp   ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  Ну люди раньше так жили да и сейчас живут))